# How to transform the center of a QQuickItem to a new center

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qquickitem

I have a Qt QML application. Following is the complete code of the application:

**Code:**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: app_main_window
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 600
    title: qsTr("Hello QML")

    Rectangle {
        id: my_item_1
        x: 100
        y: 100
        width: 100
        height: 100
        color: "grey"
        visible: true
        z: 1
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: my_item_2
        x: 400
        y: 400
        width: 100
        height: 100
        color: "grey"
        visible: true
        z: 1

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                // How can I change the center of my_item_1  to some arbitrary new center. lets say app_main_window's center. this involves another question. how can I get app_main_window's center?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Question:**
My question is simple. **How** can change the *center* of any `QQuickitem` to a new center? So in above case **how** can change the center of `my_item_1` to a new center (*Qt.point(some_x_center, some_y_center)*) when `my_item_2` gets a click event. 
**Additionally**, is possible to get another item's center? Like `app_main_window` or `my_item_2`'s center to apply to the target `my_item_1`?

**PS:**
I have made the code simple to make the question objective. I have quite a complicated logic in my actual code where I need to realign something like `my_item_1` to a new center without usage of anchors as the `QQuickitem` I am trying to do that with is scaled and panned into a new point.

Comment: If you're talking about within QML, take a look at the `anchors` property. For the implementation, you would use the `MouseArea` and `onClicked` along with `my_item_1.anchors.centerIn: app_main_window`. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: What is the problem with `anchors.centerIn` ?

Comment: @dydil one potential problem is you can only use parent or siblings with anchors.

Comment: @dydil as I said. I have a different issue which can be solved if I can change the center of `my_item_1`. this sample only has code enough demonstrate the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anchors can't be used, you have to calculate manually the center and assign it.

Quick example:

```
Item
{
    anchors.fill: parent

    Rectangle
    {
        id: nonParentOrSibling
        width: 200
        height: 200
        x: 350
        y: 240
        color: "red"
    }

}

Rectangle
{
    id: rectToMove

    width: 100
    height: 100
    y: 200
    color: "blue"

    MouseArea
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked:
        {
            var itemCenter = Qt.point(nonParentOrSibling.x + nonParentOrSibling.width / 2, nonParentOrSibling.y + nonParentOrSibling.height / 2)
            rectToMove.x = itemCenter.x - rectToMove.width / 2
            rectToMove.y = itemCenter.y - rectToMove.height / 2
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this is a one time moving only, and the rectangle won't move if the target is moved.

To make it follow the target you have to rebind it with [Qt.binding](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-propertybinding.html).

If rectToMove is not in the same coordinate system as nonParentOrSibling, you can use `Item.mapToItem()` and `mapFromItem()` to adapt the coordinates.

Comment: ok. I have to manually calculate the item center. this is something I was expecting. thanks for the answer. trying it out